# chrome-extention replace the selected text

Tags: google-chrome-extension, replace, selection

I m trying to port my firefox plugin to chrome and here is my sample code.

File: myscript.js (partial)

```
.
.
function init() {
  .
  .
  .
}
function myFunc(inp, option) {
  .
  .
  .
}

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, response) {
    switch (message) {
        case "ITRANS":
            console.log("ITRANS");
            if (document.getSelection().baseNode != null){ 
                init();
                window.modifySelection(myFunc(window.getSelection().toString(), 0)); 
            }
            break;
        case "Devanagari":
            console.log("Devanagari");
            if (document.getSelection().baseNode != null){ 
                init();
                window.modifySelection(myFunc(window.getSelection().toString(), 1)); 
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Default");
    }
});
```

File: background.js

```
var _selection_univ = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "INDIC 2 ITRANS",
    "id": "ITRANS",
    "onclick": reportclick,
    "contexts": ["selection"]
}, function () {
    console.log("Context Menu 1 ITRANS");
});
var _selection_univ = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Eng 2 Devanagari",
    "id": "Devanagari",
    "onclick": reportclick,
    "contexts": ["selection"]
}, function () {
    console.log("Context Menu 2 Devanagari");
});

function reportclick(info, tab) {
    switch (info.menuItemId) {
        case "ITRANS":
        console.log("BG: ITRANS");
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "ITRANS");
            break;
        case "Devanagari":
        console.log("BG: Devanagari");
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "Devanagari");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("BG: Default");
    }
}
```

File: manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Parivartan",
  "version": "0.8.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions":[
    "contextMenus",
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
   }
}
```

I am not able to figure out few things.

(1) Where should my init() function (which should run only once to inititialize my plugin globals) be placed.

(2) Replace the selected text with the output of a function.
    The above code does not work says "modifySelection" not found.

(3) How can call my functions if they are in a different (file2.js) file.
    At present I placed all my functions in a single file (myscript.js).

(4) How can I create menu within a menu.

I tried to search on google but could not find solutions to the above. Can anyone please help me.

-Mohan

Comment: This question needs major revamping: Be more specific about what you are trying to achieve, what your (intended) setup looks like, what files are there in your extension, whatere is the problematic code run from, what id a "menu within a menu", ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1) Where should my init() function (which should run only once to inititialize my plugin globals) be placed ?**

Depending on your requirements there are two events that should cover your initialization needs:

**[chrome.runtime.onInstalled](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onInstalled)**:

> Fired when the extension is first installed, when the extension is updated to a new version, and when Chrome is updated to a new version.

E.g.: `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {...});`

**[chrome.runtime.onStartup](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onStartup)**:

> Fired when a profile that has this extension installed first starts up. This event is not fired when an incognito profile is started, even if this extension is operating in 'split' incognito mode.

E.g.: `chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function(details) {...});`

---

**(2) Replace the selected text with the output of a function. The above code does not work says "modifySelection" not found.**

That is because the function `modifySelection` is not defined. Where did you get that name ?
***UPDATE***:
Based on OP's feedback in comments, a simple `modifySelection()` function could look like this:

```
function modifySelection(newValue) {
    var range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(newValue));
}
```

(Note: It will only work properly if the selection involves TextNodes only. In other cases it might break the DOM, so more detailed parsing of the selection is required.)

---

**(3) How can call my functions if they are in a different (file2.js) file. At present I placed all my functions in a single file (myscript.js).**

You inject all the necessary files and then you call the functions as usual. I.e. all injected content scripts are executed in the same JS context. E.g.:

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["file1.js", "file2.js", ...],
  "all_frames": true
}],
```

In `file1.js`:

```
...
function funcInFile1() {...}
...
```

In `file2.js`:

```
...
var res = funcInFile1();
...
```

(**Note**: Content scripts are injected in the order in which they appear in the "js" array. Make sure each resource is available before calling it. E.g. trying to call `funcInFile1()` before injecting `file1.js` will result in error.)

---

**(4) How can I create menu within a menu.**

If by that you mean "create a submenu", there is an `parentId` attribute that you can include in the **createProperties** argument of the **[chrome.contextMenus.create](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create)** function:

> **parentId**:
>   *The ID of a parent menu item; this makes the item a child of a previously added item.*

See, also, this **[demo extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/event_page.zip)** which does (among other things) exactly that.

---

**Some final remarks**

1. **chrome.extension.onMessage** is deprecated. Please, use **[chrome.runtime.onMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)** instead.
2. Try using **[Event Pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)** (instead of background pages) when possible.

Comment: I found modifySelection() in a sample code from internet. May be its a wrong one. May I know how to replace the selected html with the output of a function.

Comment: Maybe `modifySelection()` was implemented inthe same sample code from internet. To get it straight, do you want to achieve this: 1. User selects (highlights) some text on the page. 2. User right clickes and chooses (e.g.) "replace". 3. You extension replaces the highlighted text with something else. Is that what you 're after ?

Comment: chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function initialize() {
 init();
}); I added this  in myscript.js but gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined

Comment: And you unaccepted the answer ? Wow ! If you haf bothered to RTFM you have known better than calling it from the content script. It is available in the background page only. If you need to run init every time your script gets injected, place it in `myscript` (e.g. `window.onload = init;`).

Comment: Sorry for that. I thought if I accept the answer without mentioning the above error, it might be misleading to others who will try to use this solution. Anyhow, thanks for your answer with details.

Comment: That's why you should: 1. Not accept an answer before making sure it is worth accepting. 2. When spotting a possible problem (which turned out not to be a problem) you can kindly contact the answerer asking for clarification :)